# Ionic 2 : can't scroll all the content of the page

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

In my Ionic 2 application, i give a `margin-top : 26vh;` to ion-content.
Now when i have a long list in my page, i can't scroll all the content to the bottom, so the last part of the list is not visible.

Any idea ?

**UPDATE**

I think 26vh (same as the margin-top) on the bottom is the value of the no scrollable content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you indicated wanting to do this on ion-content. Why not just do this to see the same effect?

```
<ion-content>
  <div style="margin-top : 26vh"></div>
</ion-content>
```